# What is the difference between Neon, Fluorine-SR2, and Oxygen-SR4?

Tags: sdn, opendaylight, openflow

I am trying to program a virtual network on OpenFlow by OpenDaylight.

What is the difference between Neon, Fluorine-SR2, and Oxygen-SR4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no major change between these releases for the OpenFlow plugin. To see exact changes you can check the release notes for every release in this link: https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-fluorine/release-notes/projects/openflowplugin.html